# s3: How to recursively count files and group them by extensions - on command line in terminal

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, count

I can recursively count files in an s3 bucket like so:

```
aws s3 ls 's3://s3bucket_name/folder_name/' --recursive --summarize | grep "Total Objects: "
```

I want to now do it

1. by extension ('.jpg') - (you guys helped me there)
2. for all the extensions at once. I tried adding '--include "*." to the above but it apparently is only for copy and it failed.  I can't find anything that will do it at the command line. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You could use something like `aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket s3bucket_name --prefix folder_name/ --query "sum(Contents[?ends_with(Key,'.jpg')].Size)"`

Comment: So this will give me the Keys that end with .jpg: ```aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket s3bucket_name --prefix folder_name/ --query "(Contents[?ends_with(Key,'.jpg')])" ```

Comment: What do you mean by "for all the extensions at once"? Do you want to get a table of extensions with a count for each extension? That sounds very difficult to do.

Comment: Yes, I want to get a table or list of extensions with a count for each extension.  It doesn't sound difficult to me if it accepts a wildcard after the '.' .  I just can't figure out any wildcard that works here and I can't figure out how to count the objects that match the query where it ends with '.jpg'.